# Problem accessing MTLBuffer via typed UnsafeMutualPointer

Tags: swift, metal, swift5

I have a function that is passed an optional MTLBuffer.  My goal is to iteratively change values in that buffer using an index into a Typed pointer to the same buffer.   However, when I run the code, I'm getting an error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x1044f1000)".

Am I converting to the Typed UnsafeMutablePointer correctly?

Would it be better to covert to a Typed UnsafeMutableBufferPointer?   If so, how would I convert from the MTLBuffer to Typed UnsafeMutableBufferPointer?

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Note: I've removed most guard checks to keep this simple.  I've confirmed the MTLDevice (via device), bufferA allocation, dataPtr and floatPtr are all non-nil.  floatPtr and dataPtr do point to the same memory address.

This is how I allocate the buffer:

```
bufferSize = 16384
bufferA = device?.makeBuffer(length: bufferSize, options: MTLResourceOptions.storageModeShared)`
```

Here's my code operating on the buffer:

```
guard let dataPtr = bufferA?.contents() else {
  fatalError("error retrieving buffer?.contents() in generateRandomFloatData()")
}

let floatPtr = dataPtr.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: bufferA!.length)

for index in 0...bufferSize - 1 {
  floatPtr[index] = 1.0 // Float.random(in: 0...Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Am I converting to the Typed UnsafeMutablePointer correctly?***

NO.

When you call `makeBuffer(length:options:)` you pass the `length` in bytes.
But, a `Float` occupies 4 bytes in memory.

So, you may need to modify some parts related to number of elements:

```
let floatPtr = dataPtr.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: bufferA!.length/MemoryLayout<Float>.stride)

for index in 0..<bufferSize/MemoryLayout<Float>.stride {
  floatPtr[index] = 1.0 // Float.random(in: 0...Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
}
```